# MEF Recomposition error

Tags: export, mef

I get the exception: 
1) More than one export was found that matches the constraint: 
    ContractName    CompositionTest.C
    RequiredTypeIdentity    CompositionTest.C

When running the program

namespace CompositionTest
{

```
// [Export]  // Also doesn't work
[Export(typeof(C))]
public class C  
{
    //[ImportAttribute(AllowRecomposition = true)]  // also doesn't work
    [Import(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    public C PropertyC { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare a composition container.
        CompositionContainer compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer();

        compositionContainer.ComposeParts( new C() );  

        compositionContainer.ComposeParts( new C() );  // exception here!
    }
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The first time you call `ComposeParts`, a new `C` object is added as an export to the container. Then second time you call `ComposeParts`, another `C` object is added as an export. This creates a problem with the import because there are two possible parts for import and MEF cannot make a decision. Hence the cardinality exception.

One solution would be to change the import to:

```
[ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
public IEnumerable<C> PropertyC { get; set; }
```

Another solution is to actually use a catalog when creating the container. This is the common way to use MEF. Pretty much all the examples you can find follow this approach:

```
//Create a catalog. In this case, a catalog based on an already loaded assembly.
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(C).Assembly);
//Create a container using the catalog. Only the parts from that catalog will be used.
var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

For more on catalogs you should read this [article](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Catalogs).

By the way I have never seen such an example of MEF usage before. My answer is mainly based on observations I made while debugging it.